# Library search paths with Boost.Build

Tags: boost-build

I am trying to use Boost.Build as a C++ build system. This will included projects with have nothing to do with boost. My question is how do I get Boost.Build to add an entry to the linker's library search path. Here's my JAMFILE:

```
project RegExTest
    : requirements <include>"C:/Libraries/boost_1_57_0" <search>"C:/Libraries/boost_1_57_0/stage32/lib"
    : default-build debug
    ;

cpp-pch pch : precomp.hpp ;
exe RegExTest : [ glob *.cpp ] pch ;
```

Note that this example is using a Boost library but this in general is not the case. I don't want to use the library rule if I don't have to! I didn't need to to get my include path added so why should I have to to add a search path to the linker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the "library-path" feature to add library search paths (-L) for the linker:

```
project RegExTest
: requirements
  <include>"C:/Libraries/boost_1_57_0"
  <library-path>"C:/Libraries/boost_1_57_0/stage32/lib"
: default-build debug
;

cpp-pch pch : precomp.hpp ;
exe RegExTest : [ glob *.cpp ] pch ;
```

Unfortunately it looks like it's an undocumented feature for which you would have had to read the [source code](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/develop/src/tools/builtin.jam#L207) to find

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. Funny how the simple things are often hard and the hard things simple.